# cardinality of set of all real continuous functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, continuity, cardinals

Could somebody explain to me how to prove that the cardinality of all real continuous functions is $c$ ?

The first problem is that I don't know how to show that each real continuous function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is uniquely determined by its values for $x \in Q $.

Secondly, how to show that $R^Q \sim  R^N \sim R$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: See [Cardinality of set of real continuous functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477/cardinality-of-set-of-real-continuous-functions/) and [Can there be two distinct, continuous functions that are equal at all rationals?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505/can-there-be-two-distinct-continuous-functions-that-are-equal-at-all-rationals).