# Show that if $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ is such that $\phi(r)=r$, than $\phi$ is the classic affine function.

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Show that for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, if $r$ is such that $\phi(r)=r$, than $\phi$ is the classic affine function.

This is a personnel question, I am not able to answer. Any helps?

Comment: If $\phi$ is continuous, then as $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, $\phi$ is the identity function on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: This question makes no sense as stated.  Do you mean $\phi(r) = r$ **for all** $r \in \mathbb Q$?

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379899/why-is-every-continuous-function-at-the-reals-determined-by-its-value-on-rationa?rq=1) (and its answers) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we can take a sequence of rational numbers $\{a_n\}$ which converge to $x$ because the rationals are dense in the reals. By (sequential) continuity, 
$$
\phi(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=x
$$