# Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

The question is: Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x) = 0$ whenever $x$ is rational, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

My proof:

Let $ x\in\mathbb{R} $. If $ x\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $ f(x)=0 $.

Otherwise $ x\in\mathbb{R\backslash Q} $. Then there exists a sequence of rational numbers $ (q_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (for example $q_n= \frac{\lfloor{nx\rfloor}}{n} ,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$) such that $q_n\to x$ as $n\to \infty$. By the properties of $f$, we have $f(q_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So $f(q_n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Since $f$ is continuous, $q_n\to x$ implies that $f(q_n)\to f(x)=0$. So $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: You don't really need the "if $x\in \Bbb Q$" special case as even then there is a sequence of rational numbers converging to $x$.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you so much.

Comment: Re: Arthur's observation - while the observation is correct, I prefer the way you (Jammie) wrote it. It is just a little longer, but it makes it plainly obvious that you do, in fact, need some sort of "non-trivial" argument for irrationals, while for rational values of $x$ you don't. Well done!

Comment: As an aside, this proof can easily be extended to show that  a continuous function is completely determined by its values on the rationals.

Comment: @AndresMejia Could you elaborate further on this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379899/why-is-every-continuous-function-on-the-reals-determined-by-its-value-on-rationa

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is great (and correct, of course)!  In fact, you went above and beyond the usual proof by providing an example sequence $q_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct and strictly determined and that's how it must be, also it's really good that you provided an example sequence (the $q_n$).