# Continuity of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

So in this exact problem [$f,g$ continuous from $X$ to $Y$. if they are agree on a dense set $A$ of $X$ then they agree on $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543962/f-g-continuous-from-x-to-y-if-they-are-agree-on-a-dense-set-a-of-x-th#). My question is, what if the space given does not mention anything like say space $Y$ is not given nor given as being Hausdorff, will the statement still hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some condition is needed. If $Y$ is an indiscrete space, then every function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, so one cannot hope to define
such a function
by continuity if one only knows its values on a proper subset.

Comment: So I am confused so if the statement doesnt specify as $Y$ being Hausdorff, the statement will not hold?

Comment: The question is not about extending a partial function by continuity, but rather about two already defined functions.