# Proof: Show that if _f_ and _g_ are monotone non-increasing real-valued functions on an open real interval...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, proof-writing

Show that if *f* and *g* are monotone non-increasing real-valued functions on an open real interval *I* which agree on a dense subset of *I*, and *g* is continuous, then *f* = *g* on *I*,

and give an example to show the conclusion is *not* valid if the assumption that *g* is continuous is omitted.

Attempt: Is it similar to this:[$f,g$ continuous from $X$ to $Y$. if they are agree on a dense set $A$ of $X$ then they agree on $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543962/f-g-continuous-from-x-to-y-if-they-are-agree-on-a-dense-set-a-of-x-th) ?

Comment: It is similar, but you need to take advantage of I being an ordered set. Every number falls between sequences approaching that number, as well as the non-increasing part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D=\{x\in I: f(x)=g(x)\}$. Take any $a\in I$. 
Take increasing $c_n\in D$ and decreasing $d_n\in D$ 
with $c_n\to a$ and $d_n\to a$. By continuity, 
$g(c_n)\to g(a)$ and $g(d_n)\to g(a)$. Since $f$ is non-increasing, we have $g(c_n)=f(c_n)\ge f(a)$ and 
$f(a)\ge f(d_n)=g(d_n)$ for all $n$. Taking limits we obtain $g(a)\ge f(a)\ge g(a)$, thus $f(a)=g(a)$.

Re an example, take
$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1 \ \mathrm{if}\ 0< x\le \frac12 \\
      0 \ \mathrm{if}\ \frac12<x<1\end{cases}$ and
$g(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1 \ \mathrm{if}\ 0<x<\frac12 \\
      0 \ \mathrm{if}\ \frac12\le x<1\end{cases}$.
Note that $f$ and $g$ agree, and are continuous on the open interval $I=(0,1)$, except at $x=\frac12$, where both functions are discontinuous and $f(\frac12)\neq g(\frac12)$.