# Continuous functions that agree on the rationals are equal

Tags: continuity, terminology

It is well known that if two continuous functions, both $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, agree on the rationals then they are equal. Indeed, a more [general result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543962/f-g-continuous-from-x-to-y-if-they-are-agree-on-a-dense-set-a-of-x-th) involving dense subsets and Hausdorff spaces is true.

Does this result have a name? If not, is there a standard or obvious way to refer to it?

Comment: I don't think it has a name. The result says that a continuous function is uniquely determined by its values on a dense subset. In other words, a function defined on a dense subset has at most one continuous extension.