# Prove continuous functions $f$ and $g$ are equal

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f,g$: $\Bbb R$ → $\Bbb R$ are continuous functions such that $f(r) = g(r)$ for all $r$ in $\Bbb Q$. That is to say, $f$ and $g$ are equal on the rational numbers.

Prove that

$f(x) = g(x)$

for all $x$ in $\Bbb R$

Comment: No, you prove that. Or ask for help and tell us what you already did and what your problem is.

Comment: Hint: consider $(f - g)(x)$. It is zero on the rationals, and continuous. What does this tell you about its value on the irrationals?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can there be two distinct, continuous functions that are equal at all rationals?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505/can-there-be-two-distinct-continuous-functions-that-are-equal-at-all-rationals)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If two continuous functions agree on a dense subspace, then they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 
If $f$ is continuous then
$$
  f(x) = \lim_n f(x_n)
$$
where $x_n\to x$ is any sequence. Take a sequence of rational points...