# How to prove the uniqueness of a continuous extension of a densely defined function?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $Y$ be a Hausdorff space. Let $D$ be dense in $X$. Prove that continuous functions $f, g : X \to Y$ which are equal in $D$ are equal in all $X$.

I'm a little stuck with this elementary proof. All help appreciated :)

Comment: See
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543962/f-g-continuous-from-x-to-y-if-they-are-agree-on-a-dense-set-a-of-x-th
and maybe also
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505/can-there-be-two-distinct-continuous-functions-that-are-equal-at-all-rationals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume there is $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$.  Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, there are neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively such that $U \cap V = \emptyset$.  Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $f^{-1}(U) \cap g^{-1}(V)$ is open and nonempty (it contains $x$) in $X$ and therefore contains an element $x_0$ of $D$. Now, $f(x_0) \in U$ and, since $x_0 \in D$, $f(x_0) = g(x_0) \in V$, so $f(x_0) \in U \cap V$, contradicting the fact that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint.

Comment: $f^{-1}(U)$ and $g^{-1}(V)$ could be disjoint, though...

Comment: @fgp : $x \in f^{-1}(U) \cap g^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: Edited to mention that the inverse images can't be disjoint.