# Defining a function on $S^1$

Tags: general-topology

Can I define a function $f:S^1\to S^1$ such that $f(e^{2\pi it})=e^{2\pi i(t+\sqrt{2}k)}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. I am not sure even if this is well defined. Say this is, then is it a open map?

Comment: Related: [Describing continuous functions on $S^1/\sim$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377997).

Comment: It's a rotation of the circle about its center, through the angle $2\pi \sqrt 2 k$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(e^{2\pi i(t+1)})=e^{2\pi i(t+1+\sqrt2 k)}=e^{2\pi i(t+\sqrt 2k)}$ so $f$ is well defined

Comment: OP edited the post.

Comment: I am so sorry I did not type the function correctly. I edited it. In the previous for sure it is the identity

Comment: Any thoughts if this is an open map?

Comment: write $f_k=e^{2\pi i(t+\sqrt 2k)}$, $f_{-k}$ is the inverse of $f_k$ so $f$ is open.