# An extension of a continuous function onto the closure

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-convergence

Let $S$ be a proper subset (not closed) of a metric space $X$. Suppose that $f:S \to \Bbb R$ be continuous. I want to know the condition under which $f$ can be continuously extended to $\bar{S}$.

I am only aware of one condition when $f$ is uniformly continuous. Is there any other ?

Comment: Can't this always be done? Since a set is dense in its own closure?

Comment: @GPerez: So! let $x \in \bar{S}-S$. Then there is a sequence $\{x_n\} \in S$ which converges to $x$. Then what should we define as $f(x)$. There is no guarantee that $\{f(x_n\}$ converge as $x \not \in S$.

Comment: Hmm, I'll think about it some more then. It does work with the additional assumption that $X$ is complete though.

Comment: @GPerez: Even that is not enough. To make sure that  $\{f(x_n)\}$ cauchy when $\{x_n\}$ cauchy we need uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: Sorry, I was getting confused with [this proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/479814/118574), of a similar situation, but not really that similar I guess.

Comment: Note that if $X$ is compact, then such a function extends if and only if it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: [Linked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78637/continuous-function).

Answer (score 7):

This question was investigated in my joint with Misha Mitrofanov paper “[Approximation of continuous functions on  Fréchet spaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1814)” (at pages 794-796 of English version, which is downloadable in the source file). In particular, there I proved the following

*Lemma 2.*  Let  $X$   be a Fréchet-Urysohn topological space, $Y$  be a regular topological space, and $D$  be a dense subset of the space $X$.  A continuous mapping   $f : D\to Y$  can be extended to a continuous mapping
$\hat f : X\to Y$ iff for each sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points of the set $D$ convergent in $X$, a sequence  $\{ f(x_n)\}$ is also convergent.

which holds when both spaces $X$ and $Y$ are metric, because metric spaces are Fréchet-Urysohn and regular.