# Continuous extension from uniform continuity on relatively closed intervals of dyadic rationals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Consider the set of dyadic rationals

$$D= \{a/2^n: a,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

This is dense in $[0, \infty[$.

I have a function $f: D\to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $t > 0$, the function $f\vert_{D \cap [0,t]}$ is uniformly continuous. Is is true that $f$ has a continuous extension on $[0,\infty[$?

If yes, what theorems do you invoke to prove this?

(This question comes from a proof in Billingsley that shows that Brownian motion exists with continuous paths)

Comment: Is $F(x)=\lim_n f( 2^{-n} \lfloor x 2^n \rfloor)$ well-defined and continuous ?

Comment: Thanks @reuns. I'll try to prove that $F$ is a continuous extension.

Comment: If you have proved it, you should give an answer to your own question.

Comment: FYI, your original title was not correct, since you're not dealing with one or more dense subsets of the dyadic rationals, but rather with intervals of dyadic rationals (none of which is a dense subset of the dyadic rationals).

Comment: Yes I know but I can't make my titles arbitrarily long.

Answer (score 2):

The required claim follows from the fact that for each $t > 0$ the function $f\vert_{D \cap [0,t]}$ admits a continuous extension  and that a family $\{[0,t):t>0 \}$ is an open cover of the space $[0,\infty)$. Also it directly follows from Lemma 2 from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097819/an-extension-of-a-continuous-function-onto-the-closure/1258738#1258738) my answer.