# Detemine cardinality of $ \{ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [0,1] \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Detemine cardinality of $ \{f \mid f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [0,1] \}$.

We can show ran$(f) \neq [0,1] $  by a diagonal argument. But I am not sure how to use this to determine the cardinality.

Comment: I think you haven't read the problem carefully. No particular function $f$ can be surjective. but you're not asked about particular functions. You want the cardinality of the set of all the functions. Hint: each particular function can be thought of as a sequence of real numbers in the unit interval.

Comment: Some answers that address your question [are given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/413836/81360)