# Cardinality of each of these sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

my intuition tells me that C,D,E and F all the cardinality of the continuum and A and B have cardinality aleph null. Is this correct? I wouldn't know how to show it though and that's what I'm interested in. Here is the question:

Consider the following sets:

A = set of all infinite arithmetic progressions in $\mathbb{Z}$,

B = set of all infinite arithmetic progressions in $\mathbb{Q}$,

C = set of all infinite arithmetic progressions in $\mathbb{R}$,

D = set of all infinite sequences in $\mathbb{R}$,

E = set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$,

F = set of all closed balls in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

For each pair of these sets determine which one has larger cardinality or if they have equal cardinality.

PS: I have tried looking through the set theory section but couldn't find a similar Q and A.

Comment: Are you aware that there are cardinalities strictly greater than the cardinality of the continuum?  Have you seen the result that $x<2^x$ even for infinite cardinal numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, recall that for infinite sets you have $X$ is the same cardinality as $X^n$ for any positive integer $n$.  Here I will be using $\simeq$ to denote "has the same cardinality as."

Arithmetic progressions can be uniquely determined by two pieces of information: the starting value and the common difference.

We see then:

- $A\simeq \Bbb Z^2\simeq \Bbb N$
- $B\simeq \Bbb Q^2\simeq \Bbb N$
- $C\simeq \Bbb R^2\simeq \Bbb R$

Next, the set of infinite sequences in $\Bbb R$ can be a little tricky, but the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413836/cardinality-of-all-real-sequences) show

- $D\simeq \{f~\mid~f~:\Bbb N\times \Bbb N \to \{0,1\}\}\simeq \Bbb R$

Now, the set of all subsets of $\Bbb R$ is the [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $\Bbb R$ and by [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) we know that the power set of any set is of strictly greater cardinality.

- $E = \mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)$

Finally, the set of all closed balls in $\Bbb R^2$ can be described using three pieces of information.  The $x$-coordinate of the center of the ball, the $y$-coordinate of the center of the ball, and the radius of the ball.  We see then that

- $F \simeq \Bbb R^3\simeq \Bbb R$

Or, if you prefer, these can be written as having cardinality $\aleph_0,\mathfrak{c}, 2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ respectively

Comment: Thank you great answer. This will help me a lot.

Comment: I have one question about D: in the answers linked what does the notation {}
mean? It's been a while.

Comment: @TommySmith97 a technique called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) lets you redescribe a function which takes multiple arguments and gives an output instead as a function which takes one argument and returns a function which is then evaluated with the second argument giving the final output.  It can be applied in reverse as well, a function which takes input and returns a function which later takes other input and returns a value can be thought of as a single concise function that takes both arguments as input.

Comment: Ah thank you I think I understand.

Comment: @TommySmith97 as for what $\{f_n\}_n$ means, it is a sequence of functions.  $(f_1,f_2,f_3,\dots)$.  In this case, each function itself represents a real number and this is a sequence of real numbers, i.e. a sequence of functions.  Each function is itself a function from $\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$.