# Set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How do I prove that the Cardinality of the set of functions from Natural Numbers to Real Numbers is equal to the power set of Real Numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cardinality of all real sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413836/cardinality-of-all-real-sequences)

Comment: I didn't see this earlier. Thanks for suggesting this. However, I still don't understand the language and notations. Could you please simplify it for me?

Comment: The first thing is that a function from $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of real numbers. So your question is about the cardinality of all real sequences. The notation $A^\mathbb{N}$ is just the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ reals, so there are $\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0^2}=2^{\aleph_0}$ functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$.