# Is it true that $A^A\simeq P(A)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be an infinite set and $$A^A=\{f | f:A\to A\,\,\, \text{is a function}\}.$$
Is there any natural bijection between $A^A$ and $P(A)$?

Comment: I don't think there could be any bijection because cardinalities are different. $|A^A|=|A|^{|A|}$ but $|P(A)|=2^{|A|}$

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci: See the comments of [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/whats-the-cardinality-of-all-sequences-with-coefficients-in-an-infinite-set) I came up with this question from there.

Comment: That doesn't mean their cardinalities are different,@AlbertoAndrenucci For example $|2^{\mathbb N}|=|\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}|$

Comment: The question is about a "natural bijection", or whether a bijection exists? I don't know how to find a natural bijection between $A$ and $A\times A$ for $A$ infinite. Or even between $A$ and $A \sqcup A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You need to know for infinite $A$ that $|A\times A|=|A|$, and that for any $A$, $|P(A)^A|=|P(A\times A)|$.

It's obvious that $|P(A)|\leq |A^A|$, so you need to show that $|A^A|\leq |P(A)|$.

Comment: In terms of cardinal arithmetic, we might expect that $|(2^A)^A| = |2^{A \times A}|$.  A nice bijection between $(2^{A})^A$ and $2^{A \times A}$ is given by ["uncurrying"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 2):

$|A|^{|A|} \le |\mathscr{P}(A)|^{|A|} = (2^{|A|})^{|A|} = 2^{|A \times A|} = 2^{|A|} \le |A|^{|A|}$, so we have equality.

Comment: Wow! very nice one line solution.

Comment: If you know the rules of cardinal arithmetic, yes

Answer (score 2):

There is a natural injective function $F : A^A \to P(A\times A)$:

$$F(f)=\{ (x,f(x)) | x \in A \}$$
(ie $f \to Graph(f)$).

This shows that 
$$|A^A| \leq |P(A \times A)|=|P(A)|$$

Also, there is a natural injective function $G : P(A) \to A^A$ given by the 
characteristic function. Indeed, fix two elements $a,b \in A$ and then define
$G(B)(x)=a$ if $x \in B$ and $G(B)(x)=b$ if $x \notin B$.

Comment: Wait, so if I understand this correctly, we don't need any form of choice anywhere, right? (The other two answers use $|A \times A| = |A|$ for infinite $A$.)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani The answer also uses that result, namely in the step $|P(A \times A)|=|P(A)|$.