# On the cardinality of $\mathbb{N} ^{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

Tags: cardinals

Actually, I have been trying to find out the cardinality of these two sets stated above. 
    Obviously,  $\mid 2^{\mathbb{R}} \mid \leq \mid \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{R}} \mid$ , but what is the atmost value of the cardinality of the set in right hand side ??? 
              I was thinking to differentiate between two functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{N}$ using the decimal representation of reals in $[0,1]$ , but couldn't proceed .
     And, please I want some hints about $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} $ .

Comment: Can please someone format this question on LateX or MathJax (as I am completely unable of doing it ) ???

Comment: @Asaf Karaglia,Thank you Sir, for editing.

Comment: I've only removed the irrelevant large cardinals tag. The rest was done by others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $|\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$ and $|\mathbb{R}| = 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$.
Using [cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic), we have

$$ |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{N}|^{|\mathbb{R}|} = {\aleph_0}^\mathfrak{c} = {\aleph_0}^{2^{\aleph_0}}  = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}} = \beth_2 $$

and

$$ |\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{R}|} = \mathfrak{c}^\mathfrak{c} = (2^{\aleph_0})^\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\mathfrak{c}\,\aleph_0} = 2^\mathfrak{c} = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}} = \beth_2 $$

(also see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/whats-the-cardinality-of-all-sequences-with-coefficients-in-an-infinite-set/14434#14434) for exponentiation of cardinals.)

---

If the [generalized continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis) is true, then all of the different cardinalities above can be written as $\aleph$ numbers: $\mathfrak{c} = \aleph_1$ and $\beth_2 = \aleph_2$.

Comment: GCH is irrelevant: both sets are size $2^\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: True. GCH is only for writing it as an equivalent $\aleph$ number

Comment: It only confuses matters. Don't mention it at all.

Comment: I moved it to a footnote below the main answer.

Comment: You're mixing notations pretty badly. You have $\frak c$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, and you bring up $\beth$ numbers into the picture...

Comment: I don't see what exactly is incorrect though.

Comment: Did I say that you're using them *incorrectly*? I said that you're mixing the different notations and that it looks pretty bad.

Comment: Would be more helpful if you pointed out how to improve it.