# How to prove this $\vert C^*(X)\vert \leq 2^{d(X)}$

Tags: general-topology

The continuous functions is determined by a dense subset of X, that is, $\vert C^*(X)\vert\leq\vert C^*(D)\vert$.

The [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function#Cardinal_functions_in_topology) $d(X)$ of a space $X$ is the smallest cardinality of a dense subset of $X$. To be more precise
$$d(X)=\aleph_0+\min\{|D|; D\subseteq X\text{ is dense}\}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is a dense subset of $X$ such that $|D|=d(x)$, then the cardinality of the set of all real-valued continuous functions is less or equal to the cardinality of the set of all real-valued functions defined on the set $D$, i.e., $\mathfrak c^{d(X)}=2^{\aleph_0 d(X)}$.

Can you take it from there?

---

The basic idea is almost the same as in the proof that the cardinality of $C(\mathbb R)$ is $\mathfrak c$: [Cardinality of set of real continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477/cardinality-of-set-of-real-continuous-functions).

Comment: I think that this question (or a very similar question) was asked before. But if there is a duplicate, I was not able to find it.