# Cardinality of the set of continuous functions which have the same integral value on some interval

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Suppose that we take some continuous real function of a real variable $f$ which is defined on the set $[a,b]$ and that we have $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\alpha$.

Now, let us denote by $SIV_{\alpha}([a,b])$ the set of functions such that we have, if $g \in SIV_{\alpha}([a,b])$ then $g$ is defined on $[a,b]$, $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx=\alpha$.

So $SIV_{\alpha}([a,b])$ is the set of all real functions of a real variable which are defined and continuous on the set $[a,b]$ and whose integral on the set $[a,b]$ is equal $\alpha$.

Let now $C([a,b])$ be the set of all continuous real functions of a real variable defined on the set $[a,b]$.

> Does there exist bijection between the sets $C([a,b])$ and $SIV_{\alpha}([a,b])$?

Comment: You can delete the first paragraph $-f$ plays no further part in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The cardinality of $SIV_{\alpha}([a,b])$ is equal to the one of $C([a,b])$ which is equal to the one of $\mathbb R$, i.e. the cardinality of the continuum.

To see that $C([a,b])$ has the cardinality of the continuum, you can have a look to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477/cardinality-of-set-of-real-continuous-functions).

Then it is easy to see that $SIV_{\alpha}([a,b])$ has also at least the cardinality of the continuum as you can find $f \in SIV_{\alpha}([a,b])$ with $f(a)$ equal to whatever real number you want. As the cardinality of $SIV_{\alpha}([a,b])$ is obviously less than or equal to the one of $C([a,b])$, you're done.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to exhibit an explicit bijection between the two sets. I suppose it must be, because I can't see the Axiom of Choice anywhere here. (PS I think "obviously less than" should be "obviously less than or equal to".)

Comment: Using the  Cantor Bernstein theorem which has a constructive version, we just have to find a one-to-one map from $SIV_\alpha ([a, b]) $ into $C([a, b]) $.

Comment: Unfortunately, in English you really do have to say "less than or equal to". "Less or equal than" doesn't cut it.

Comment: Thanks for the English lesson! Not so easy to be precise in a different language as there are a lot of tricky differences... That change mathematical meaning.