# Cardinality of continuous functions $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cardinals

> Cardinality of continuous functions $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$.

We know that a continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is completely determined by its values on $\Bbb Q$.

For each rational $q\in \Bbb Q,f(q)$ has $c(=\text{Card }\Bbb R)$ many choices.

Hence the number of such functions becomes $\mathfrak{q^c}= \Bbb N^c$ .

Is it right?Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct. For starters, the expression $q^\mathfrak{c}$ (where $q\in\Bbb Q$) is meaningless; I suspect that you meant $\left|\Bbb Q^\mathfrak{c}\right|$, which is indeed $\left|\Bbb N^\mathfrak{c}\right|$. But note that you do need the cardinality bars.

However, you’ve got the multiplication principle backwards: you’re making a choice amongst $\mathfrak{c}$ real numbers $|\Bbb Q|$ times, so you really want $\mathfrak{c}^{|\Bbb N|}$. Finally, $\mathfrak{c}=2^{|\Bbb N|}$, so

$$\mathfrak{c}^{|\Bbb N|}=\left(2^{|\Bbb N|}\right)^{|\Bbb N|}=2^{|\Bbb N|\cdot|\Bbb N|}=2^{|\Bbb N|}=\mathfrak{c}\;.$$

This actually shows only that there are *at most* $\mathfrak{c}$ continuous real-valued functions on $\Bbb R$, since it counts *all* functions from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb R$, not just the ones that are restrictions of continuous functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. To complete the argument you need to show that there are also *at least* that many; this is easy, since there are $\mathfrak{c}$ constant functions.

I’ve answered this in order to respond to the specific problems with your argument. The question itself has been dealt with in detail in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477/cardinality-of-set-of-real-continuous-functions).

Comment: One question?Why can't we conclude from the first para that there are exactly $\mathfrak c$ functions?Why do we state at most $\mathfrak c$ many functions?Since for each $q\in \Bbb Q\exists\mathfrak  c$ many choices so can't we conclude that number of such functions is exactly $\mathfrak c$ as above

Comment: Why do we need to use constant functions to guarantee at least $\mathfrak c$?Would be glad if u could help.

Comment: @Ben: You’re welcome. \\ The functions that you’re counting aren’t necessarily continuous; there are $\mathfrak{c}$ of them, but it’s conceivable that fewer than that many are continuous. \\ We don’t have to use the constant functions to guarantee that there are at least $\mathfrak{c}$ continuous functions; any set of $\mathfrak{c}$ continuous functions would work. But they’re one of the easiest ways to do so: they are very easily seen to be continuous, and it’s immediately clear that there are $\mathfrak{c}$ of them.

Comment: @Ben: You’re very welcome.