# Find the cardinality of the set of all norms on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I have found the upper bound for the set of all norms, but I'm unsure as how to find the lower bound. I have already shown that the cardinality set of continuous functions from  $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is the continuum

Suppose $\|\|$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and defined the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\|x\|$. We prove that $f$ is continuous. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=x$, i.e. $\|x_n-x\| \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

To prove that $f$ is continuous it is enough to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$$

Using the revered triangle inequality we have

$$\|f(x_n)-f(x)\|=\| x_n\| -\|x\| \leq \| x_n -x \| \rightarrow 0$$

Hence

$$\|f(x_n)-f(x)\| \to 0$$

which means
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$$

So the cardinality of the set of all norms is at most that of the set of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you know that the cardinality of the set of continuous functions $\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is the same as the cardinality as $\mathbb R$? (e.g. as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477/cardinality-of-set-of-real-continuous-functions)). I suspect that's the only piece you're missing to finish the argument.

Comment: @MiloBrandt yes i have this, but don't I need to show that the lower bound of the set of norms is also the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $\|\cdot \|$ is a norm, $\|\cdot \|_{\alpha}=\alpha\|\cdot\|$ is a norm for any positive real $\alpha.$ @JustinSoanes

Comment: @ThomasAndrews well, for any positive $a$

Comment: Yep, fixed. @alan